# Having if/else trouble while creating a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, if-statement

I'm having trouble with a homework assignment.

Everything works as expected except for the `letter_grade` part. I'm not getting any compile errors, but every time I run the program, the `letter_grade` is -858993460. I know it's probably something simple that I am overlooking, but I've hit a wall and am pretty much out of ideas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Class Declaration

class StudentRecord
{
  string id;
  int A, B, C, D, F, grade;
  float avg, exam1, exam2;

public: 
  void input();
  void output();
  void average();
  void letter_grade();
};

// Gathering data

void StudentRecord::input()
{

  cout << " Please enter your student ID: ";
  cin >> id;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Enter your score for exam 1: ";
  cin >> exam1;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Enter your score for exam 2: ";
  cin >> exam2;
}

// Calculations

void StudentRecord::average()
{
  avg = (exam1 + exam2) / 2;
}

void StudentRecord::letter_grade()
{
  if ((avg >= 90) && (avg <= 100))
    grade = A;
  else if ((avg >= 80) && (avg < 90))
    grade = B;
  else if ((avg >= 70) && (avg < 80))
    grade = C;
  else if ((avg >= 60) && (avg < 70))
    grade = D;
  else (avg < 60);
  grade = F;
}

// Output Data

void StudentRecord::output()
{
  cout << "\n\n";
  cout << " *** Student Record ***" << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Student ID: " << id << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Grade for exam 1: " << exam1 << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Grade for exam 2: " << exam2 << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Average for the class: " << avg << endl;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << " Letter grade for the class: " << grade << endl;
  cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
  StudentRecord student;
  student.input();
  student.average();
  student.letter_grade();
  student.output();

  system ("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: None of the variables `A - F` are initialized.  If you want to output an actual letter use a `char` variable and assign `'A'`, etc. to it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Note that in all of those `if` statements you could remove two-thirds of the parentheses without changing the meaning.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but those `if` statements do more tests than are needed. The first `if` handles values that are `>= 90', so the next one does have to check that the value is `< 90`. Similarly through the rest: the second check check isn't needed, because the preceding `if` already did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared integer variables named `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc.  That's not really what you want here.  You want to declare `grade` as a `char` variable.  You want to put the character `'A'`, `'B'`, etc. in that `char` variable.

Example:

```
grade = 'A';
```

That puts the character `'A'` into the variable `grade`.

If you remove those variables `A`...`F`, change `grade` to be of type `char`, and then rewrite your `if`-`else` statement to assigned letters `'A'`, `'B'`, etc. to `grade`, that should do the trick.

Take note of those single quotes around the characters.  Those tell C++ that the thing between the quotes is a character constant.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the "grade" values , A,B,C,D,F as integers.  They are never initialized, so contain garbage in them.  I think your intent was to print out a letter grade.  In that case, you need to represent the values as strings, not numbers.  Something like this:

```
char *A = "A";
char *B = "B";
etc.
```

The declaration of a variable is simply a label to identify a memory location ( simplified ).  So, the name of the variable has no correlation to its value.